# A Typed array of functions - using this reference

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a interface that defines the a interface with a array of functions and a this guard as below:

```
interface MyInterface {
  myFunctions: ((this:MyInterface, somevar: string): void)[];
}
```

But , when i try to use it as below:

```
class Myclass implements MyInterface {
  myFunctions: ((this:Implementation, somevar: string): void)[];
  useFunction (): void {
    this.myFunctions[0](somevar);
  }
}
```

The erro below happens
    Class 'Myclass ' incorrectly implements interface 'MyInterface'

Somebody knows how i do implements that ??

Comment: Your class implementation is different from your interface, so that's not allowed. I'm also not sure how an interface can have a function that implements itself ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, function type is declared with `=>` , not `:`

```
interface MyInterface {
  myFunctions: ((this:MyInterface, somevar: string) => void)[];
}
```

Second, why do you have `this:Implementation` in the class, not `this.MyClass` or `this.MyInterface` as declared in the interface? It should be consistent - either `this.Implementation` in the both class and interface, or `this.MyInterface` in the interface and `this.MyClass` in the class.

Then, in javascript (and typescript), for calling a function and setting it's `this` context the function name must be followed immediately by `(`, for example `this.useFunction()`.

You have `this.myFunctions[0](somevar)` which means that you are calling the first element of `myFunctions` as free function, without setting its `this` context. You need to set `this` explicitly using [call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) here:

```
interface MyInterface {
  myFunctions: ((this:MyInterface, somevar: string) => void)[];
}

class Myclass implements MyInterface {
    myFunctions: ((this: Myclass, somevar: string) => void)[] = [];


    useFunction(somevar: any): void {
        this.myFunctions[0].call(this, somevar);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, the first error about how the function is declared was just my bad, it was like you said in the original source.